# PHP PDO Class SELECT OR

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using a PHP PDO class which you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/VLh2cFbv) and having some problems. If I will use a simple select where, this is the code:

```
$id = 54;
$bind = array(
    ":aid" => $id,
    ":aid" => $id2,
);
$results = $db->select("accounts", "AccountID = :aid", $bind);
```

This is the select function from the claass:

```
public function select($table, $where="", $bind="", $fields="*") {
                $sql = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
                if(!empty($where))
                        $sql .= " WHERE " . $where;
                $sql .= ";";
                return $this->run($sql, $bind);
        }
```

My problem is I want to perform an OR, there. How can I do that?

Comment: If your question is about your PDO class, maybe you should put the corresponding method in the question

Comment: You cant recycle the same placeholder,they have to be different

Comment: An associative array can't have two elements with the same key. `array(':aid' => $id, ':aid' => $id2)` makes no sense.

Comment: @Barmar How'd you get the last insert ID using this function?

Comment: @Mihai How'd you get the last insert ID using this function?

Comment: @FewFlyBy You're not doing an `INSERT`, so there's no last insert ID to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the select function you can simply use

```
$id = 54;
$something=123;

$bind = array(
    ":aid" => $id,
    ":something" => $something
);

$results = $db->select("accounts", "AccountID = :aid OR AccountID=:something ", $bind);
```